# bibliography doesn' t appear, even though I have the .bbl

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using TeXworks and have a problem with BibTeX. I compiled the `.bbl` file however I can't see the bibliography in the output.

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\begin{document}
 bu bir denemedir.\cite{Sripirom20112402}.

\bibliographystyle{plane}
\thebibliography{tryin}
\end{document}
```

If I type in like above `.tex`, I can see only the title of bibliography and when I type `\bibliography{tryin}`, I get nothing.

Comment: I think you need to fix a couple of typos: First, use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plane}`; second, you do need to type `\bibliography{tryin}` instead of `\thebibliography{tryin}`. You are following the usual procedure of running (pdf)latex, then bibtex, then latex twice more, right? If so, check the log files (.log and .blg) and examine them for errors and/or warnings.

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't provide a compilable example, I can only make some (hopefully educated) guesses: The `plane` style is probably a typo and should be replaced with `plain`. Also, replace `\thebibliography` with `\bibliography`.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{tryin}
```

Comment: thank you for realizing my wrong typing. that was such a stupidity of me. Thank you so much:)

Comment: @AhmetSadıkYorulmaz You may also thank me by upvoting my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).